# Error after using "<style lang="scss" scoped>"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass

am using some code from github and got Errror after using

Any tip ? Am quite new into js and vue ... got problems with modules all the time.

I Tried

```
npm uninstall webpack
```

and then

```
npm install webpack@^4.0.0 --save-dev
```

It's still not working :( tried even other versions... Thx for help .. btw this is my first post :D sorry if something is wrong

```html
Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude) in {
  "exclude": [
    null
  ],
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "C:\\Users\\kopem\\Desktop\\práce\\VueJs\\project-01\\node_modules\\cache-loader\\dist\\cjs.js",
      "options": {
        "cacheDirectory": "C:\\Users\\kopem\\Desktop\\práce\\VueJs\\project-01\\node_modules\\.cache\\babel-loader",
        "cacheIdentifier": "50b893d9"
      },
      "ident": "clonedRuleSet-38.use[0]"
    },
    {
      "loader": "C:\\Users\\kopem\\Desktop\\práce\\VueJs\\project-01\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\lib\\index.js",
      "options": "undefined",
      "ident": "undefined"
    }
  ]
}
Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude) in {
  "exclude": [
    null
  ],
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "C:\\Users\\kopem\\Desktop\\práce\\VueJs\\project-01\\node_modules\\cache-loader\\dist\\cjs.js",
      "options": {
        "cacheDirectory": "C:\\Users\\kopem\\Desktop\\práce\\VueJs\\project-01\\node_modules\\.cache\\babel-loader",
        "cacheIdentifier": "50b893d9"
      },
      "ident": "clonedRuleSet-38.use[0]"
    },
    {
      "loader": "C:\\Users\\kopem\\Desktop\\práce\\VueJs\\project-01\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\lib\\index.js",
      "options": "undefined",
      "ident": "undefined"
    }
  ]
}
    at checkResourceSource (C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:167:11)
    at Function.normalizeRule (C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:198:4)
    at C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:110:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalizeRules (C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:109:17)
    at new RuleSet (C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:104:24)
    at new NormalModuleFactory (C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:115:18)
    at Compiler.createNormalModuleFactory (C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:636:31)
    at Compiler.newCompilationParams (C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:653:30)
    at Compiler.compile (C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:661:23)
    at C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:77:18
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:24:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Watching._go (C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:41:32)
    at C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:33:9
    at Compiler.readRecords (C:\Users\kopem\Desktop\práce\VueJs\project-01\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:529:11)
```

Comment: The `lang` attribute describes the **human** language for an element (e.g. `en-US` for American English) and has no place on a `<style>` element which doesn't contain any human language.

Comment: The [`scoped` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement/scoped) isn't part of HTML any more. Don't use it.

Comment: Your error message appears to be related to your Webpack configuration, and not your HTML.

Comment: @Quentin Please don´t spread the information, that `scoped` isn´t used anymore, as it is a basic feature of `vue.js`. Please read: [Scoped CSS](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles)

Answer (score 0):

In `vue.js` you can declare global or local styles. You should and can use the `<style>`-tag in `vue.js` like this:

```
<style>
/* global styles */
</style>
```

Styles in this tag, would be valid global in your `vue.js` app.

```
<style scoped>
/* local styles */
</style>
```

Styles in this tag, would only be valid in the component, where you declared this `<style scoped>`-tag.

For more information, just read this documentation: [Scoped CSS](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles)

Comment: The lang attribute does belong - that's how you indicate to Vue that the CSS is SCSS https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass